# How to password protect usage of USB drives Windows machine?

Tags: windows, usb, virus

My clients like to plug in USB drives into the computers to install games, etc, resulting in virus and trojan infection.  Is there a way I can password protect usage of USB drives on Windows machine?  The computers do not have Internet connection.

It will be good if the method works for CDROM also.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer:
Go into the Group Policy Editor > User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Installer and change the "Prevent removable media source for any install" value to "enabled". This will stop install from CD/DVDs but I'm not sure if it applies to USB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DevicePro Agent for this limitation: https://cynapspro.com/US/products/devicepro

> Devicepro ® controls the interface to portable media devices allowing
>   users to benefit from the advantages of mobile media, without risking
>   the loss of data or the introduction of malware. DevicePro® enables
>   you to determine which mobile storage media is allowed in your
>   network, which ports may be used and what file types can be imported
>   from or exported to external media. Real-time management, flexible
>   access settings, and full support for mobile users ensure a high
>   degree of acceptance among users.